# Parcelable object array causes NullPointerException when I try to pass Parcelable as Bundle in Intent

Tags: android, parcelable

Often I use Parcelable and Bundle without problems, but this time I need to include in my parcelable object, an array of other Parcelable Objects, but unfortunately something goes wrong and I get a NullPointerException, so certainly I have made some mistake in the Parcelable configuration, but I haven't understood how to fix it.

Here my attempt

```
    public class CarConfig implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    Car cars[];
    int speed;

    public CarConfig(Car[] cars, int speed) {
        super();
        this.cars = cars;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public CarConfig() {

    }


    public static Parcelable.Creator<CarConfig> getCreator() {
        return CREATOR;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
        arg0.writeParcelableArray(cars, 0);
        arg0.writeInt(speed);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CarConfig> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CarConfig>() {
        public CarConfig createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CarConfig(in);
        }

        public CarConfig[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CarConfig[size];
        }
    };

    private CarConfig(Parcel in) {
        Parcelable[] p = in.readParcelableArray(Car.class.getClassLoader());
        cars = new Car[p.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            cars[i] = (Car) p[i];
        }
        speed = in.readInt();

    }

}
```

Here the error log

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to com.myapp.uk.CarConfig 
at com.myapp.uk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:98)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The crash happens exactly when I try to get the object in the destination activity with

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
cg = bundle.getParcelable("DataKey");
```

Comment: The actual stack trace would help.

Comment: @wsanville I have added the log, however I am almost sure that the issue is related to a bad use of parcelable for array of parcelable object in my CarConfig class above, but I don't know how to fix it.